# Informatica Pre Session Command read files matching a pattern inside a directory and delete "" in files

Tags: shell, unix, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I've researched a lot and finally made a decision to raise this question. I am using Informatica Pre Session command to read files that match a particular pattern and delete all "" characters inside those files.
Also once that is done I need to delete the very last line.

On Individual files I'm able to do that using below:

````
#To remove Double Quotes from the file

sed -i -e 's/\"//g' /opt/informed/file_name_20200801.txt

# This works for individual files but next I'm trying to loop through a directory 
#with matching file names and delete quotes in all files in the directory

for file in opt/informed/file_name_*.txt; do 
        sed 's/\"//g' "$file" >> /opt/informed/"$file";
done;

#It runs without error but nothing happens. I want to edit the existing files to get rid of 
#any double quotes in those files. ```

#Once I'm able to achieve that, I can apply a similar loop to process the files 
#to delete last #line of each file using:

sed -e '$d' /opt/informed/filename.txt >> filename.txt #Works for individual Files
````

Comment: You are looking for `-i` option for `sed` tool. Try this on a single file and then you could run this on multiple files too `sed -i 's/\"//g'  Input_file` this will remove all occurrences of `"` and save the changes into Input_file itself.

Comment: So is the for loop correct? just place -i in front of sed and run the for loop command for multiple files should do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Please use below script,

Replaces the double quotes

```
for file in opt/informed/file_name_*.txt; 
do 
        sed 's/\"//g' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file";
done;
```

Removes the header

```
for file in opt/informed/file_name_*.txt;  
do 
    sed -i '$d' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file";
done;
```

The code loops each file and redirects to the `tmp` and then `moves` to the original file name.

Provided you two different codes to understand it clearly. You  can merge it in a single script and call it in informatica pre session command

Comment: The `-i` option performs the change in-place by replacing the original file with the output automatically. So you could add that to the 1st snippet and remove the `> tmp && mv tmp "$file";` part from both. Please refer https://archive.is/cLlnm#selection-795.0-829.59